# Can Gmail read password protected .docx files?

Tags: file-encryption, gmail, office

Can Gmail read MS-Word .docx 2011 (OS X) files that require a password to open?

As I understand it, Gmail servers read emails and attachments in their efforts to characterize users for advertising purposes. If there is sensitive information, one would encrypt the sensitive message.

It is not clear if .docx are encrypted. Maybe the right question to ask is: How does one verify that the target .docx file is encrypted?

Comment: Can you please elaborate as the question is not clear...

Comment: I'm not at my pen testing machine right now, but the test seems pretty straight-forward: 1) save a .docx with some text in it, 2) save another copy with password-protect on, 3) open both in a hex editor to see what changes when you password-protect, and play around to see if you can extract the string.

Comment: Working through this question: https://superuser.com/q/486844 should more or less answer your question.  In short "locking" a document provides no protection at all.  Password protecting a document (which sounds like is the case here) does, as office uses strong encryption.